# Get Twig start of day date_modify

Tags: php, twig

I am trying to get the start of today's date and time in Twig. I found that you can get the start of the current week by doing the following:

`{{ now | date_modify('monday this week')|date('d-m-y H:i:s') }}`

So I assume there will be a way to do this for the start of today. So far, I have tried:

`{{ now | date_modify('start of day')|date('d-m-y H:i:s') }}`

`{{ now | date_modify('start of today')|date('d-m-y H:i:s') }}`

Which resulted in:

> PHP Warning:  DateTime::modify(): Failed to parse time string (start of day) at position 0
>
> PHP Warning:  DateTime::modify(): Failed to parse time string (start of today) at position 0

I would like to know:

1. What is the correct syntax to ask this?
2. Where can I find a list of these strings?
3. Any alternatives to passing in strings

Thank you.

Comment: You can only used the strings in the documentation. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: What do you mean by start of day? midnight of the current date?

Comment: @blupointmedia yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find those strings here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php.

So I think what are you looking for is this:
`{{ now | date_modify('today') | date('d-m-y h:m:s') }}`

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I had no idea that it was PHP not Twig!

Comment: @party-ring no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ date('today') | format_datetime() }}
```

`date` (as well as `date_modify`) uses PHP’s `strtotime` function. `today` refers to 00:00:00 of the current day, as stated in [PHP’s relative format reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).